# jwplayer 6 change the movie time look

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm looking for a way to change the display of the movie time.
is it possible to change from 01:30 to 1:30?

I couldn't find an API for that

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/topics/601064-customization/articles

Comment: That is not possible to change I'm afraid.